# String comparison with gte and lte in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a field in one of my mongodb collection that stores date in below format:

```
{
 name:"ABC",
 LAST_UPDATED:"10/10/2022 6:0"
},
{
 name:"ABC",
 LAST_UPDATED:"10/10/2022 6:15"
}
...
```

New data is added to this collection every 15 min.Everyday this collection will be cleaned at 12AM, so the date would be same in every document. Now I want to query for documents which have `LAST_UPDATED` time between 6:30 and 8:45. I have written below query:

```
 db.collection_name.find({$and:[{LAST_UPDATED:{$gte:"10/10/2022 6:30"}},{LAST_UPDATED:{$lte:"10/10/2022 8:15"}}]});
```

The issue is that above query works only for some time ranges. It doesn't work for every input. I cannot also use mongodb date format.

Is there any way to find documents in a given time range considering that the format of `LAST_UPDATED` field will not be changed?

Thank You!

Comment: I don't think there is any solution to your problem without changing the `LAST_UPDATED` field. It makes no sense to store date as string. Your sample data even seems dont have a consistent format to be parsed by `$dateFromString`. Always store as proper date object for querying on a date field.

Comment: So you're storing dates in a string, as month/day/year? Note that this does not sort properly (you'd need to save dates as year/month/day). Also you need to zero-pad all dates and times so that you can sort properly (e.g. `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`). This is likely directly related to your range-checking issues.

Comment: @ray - dates *can* be stored as string, but not in the format the OP chose, if there is any need for searching/sorting. Needs to be ISO 8601 format...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Of course dates can be stored as strings. It is just generally considered an anti-pattern as it introduces unnecessary complexity to query.

Comment: As mentioned in previous comments, the string format of `"LAST_UPDATED"` is unfortunate.  If `"LAST_UPDATED"` can't be stored as a BSON Date, then you could convert `"LAST_UPDATED"` to a BSON Date using [`"dateFromString"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) and then proceed "normally".  Of course doing your queries like this means that an index can't be used and the performance will suffer.